# How to select a range of numpy array in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

| Train ID | adc_data1 |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | [1610,1613,1616,...] |
| 102 | [1601,1605,1610,...] |
| ... | ... |

in the "adc_data1" column, in each cell there is a numpy array. I would like to select a range of data from each cell in this column and put it in a new column and creat a dataframe as below. How does one do this?

| Train ID | adc_data1 | selected data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | [1610,1613,1616,...] | [1610,1613,1616] |
| 102 | [1601,1605,1610,...] | [1601,1605,1610] |
| ... | ... | ... |

Using the line below one can select a range of data for a single cell:

```py
    selected_range = df["adc_data1"].iloc[1][0:2]
```

but is there a way to do the same for all rows at the same time without using a for loop?

Comment: Does my answer help you? You can try `df['adc_data1'].str[:2]` in your example

Comment: yes it worked, tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
df["adc_data1"].str[0:100]
```

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[list(range(1000))]]*3, columns=['adc_data1'])
print(df["adc_data1"].str[:10])
```

Output:

```
0    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Name: adc_data1, dtype: object
```